# How to deploy a java application that runs as server over internet?

Tags: java, mysql, server

i want to host a java program that run as a server over internet accepting TCP UDP connections over internet. We have a machine with a fixed IP. It (Java program) also handles database(Mysql) that resides on same machine. My question is that do i need to learn Application servers like Jboss etc to handle this? I just want to avoid complexity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can go with this. It all depends on what you want really.

If you are serving a website, I strongly suggest a framework to handle all of your requests and website logic. A good choice would be Play Framework (for both Java and Scala):

- [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/)

But if you don't like it, you can always check its competitors:

- [Spring](https://spring.io/)
- [JavaEE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html)

If however, you are doing something different (lets say you need a way to contact a server for an internal network), you can also use RMI and code the the response on your own. Following are some RMI examples:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/hello/hello-world.html
- https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~cappello/lectures/rmi/helloworld.shtml
- http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/javarmi/javarmi.html

Note that RMI also works for networks that are not internal (it was just an example).

Overall, you have a lot of choices and documentation you can use. JBoss is also an option you have (no question about that) but if you really want something simple, with no frameworks or extra tools, you can go with RMI, or Java Sockets:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm

Hope it helps !

Comment: Okay :). The java program will be accepting locations (consider string data) from mobile phones sent over internet. I have to process them. There will be clients requesting this program for these details and those requests must be processed. My concern is if I want to host this application over internet by application hosting, can i keep it simple by as you said just using RMI and sockets. I am also thinking of same. : )

Comment: Yes you can keep it simple just like that. If I may suggest a great book on the matter:
https://www.amazon.com/Network-Programming-Elliotte-Rusty-Harold/dp/1449357679/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1466152404&sr=8-1&keywords=java+network . It has many examples, and it helped me a lot during my time. You can probably get a pdf version on the internet, but that this place is not to discuss such things :P